# JavaScript callback function(reference) accepting an argument without constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, callback, arguments, es6-promise

Test returns a promise following which the 'then' method's call back is given the function test2 which console.logs the string "hello" as expected.

However, what is the name(if there is one) to the way test2 as a callback accepts the "hello" as the 'someString' argument using a function reference and not explicitly via writing the callback in the 'then' method with a constructor or how does it work behind the scenes?

```
async function test(){
 return "hello"
}

function test2(someString){
    console.log(someString);
}
//Here test2 accepts the return from test() which is "hello" without it being explicitly fed into test2 e.g. test2(arg)
test().then(test2);
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Can you please show what you mean by _the way test2 as a callback accepts the "hello" as the 'someString' argument_?

Comment: The argument is implicitly passed. JavaScript is weakly typed, and arguments can be omitted and you can pass more arguments that a function expect - `test2` is just a reference to a function that is called internally by `Promise.then` with the resolved value. When you write explicitly `.then((res) => test2(res))` you are also passing a function  reference.

Comment: You know that a constructor is a function used to initialize an instance of a class?

Comment: @briosheje The then() method is given test2 function as a callback, question is how it is able to accept the 'someString' argument

Comment: @goodness Li357 above already answers your question ;)

Comment: @Li357 cannot accept your comment as the answer here

Answer (score 0):

Here `test2` type is `function`. `then()` would figure out that this is a function and would appropriately and can easily call that function as we do by passing result argument from previous promise.